# Custom Security mechanism in Java EE 6/7 application

Tags: security, jboss7.x, java-ee-6, java-ee-7, wildfly

I would like to create (implement by my own) authentication mechanism which will be
plugged into my Java EE application.

As far as I know I have to implement LoginModule and connect this implementation with 
container mechanisms somehow.  But the problem is that I don't know how to do it. 
Maybe You know where I can find sample code or tutorial about it?

In other words I would like to force container to call my classes whenever methods:
authenticate, login, and logout are called.

**Sample implementation**:
HttpServletRequest.login method will successfully authenticate only users with even numer of letters in login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading about JAAS, you should implement your login module basing on *org.jboss.security.auth.spi.AbstractServerLoginModule* (from *org.picketbox/picketbox* maven artifact). Then deploy the module with your app, and create a proper security domain and realm in WildFly's standalone.xml, like such:

```
<security-domain name="myDomain" cache-type="default">
  <authentication>
    <login-module code="com.example.TestLoginModule" flag="required" 
module="deployment.sample.jar"/>
  </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

...

```
<security-realm name="MyRealm">
 <authentication>
   <jaas name="myDomain"/>
 </authentication>
</security-realm>
```

Look out for different behaviour on different JBoss AS versions. 7.1.1 will not allow you to deploy the login module, you would have to create a separate jboss module and bind it with org.picketbox and jboss.security modules.

Additional reading:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Security+subsystem+configuration

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Security+Realms

http://java.dzone.com/articles/creating-custom-login-modules (it is a little outdated, but the gives the main idea)

Comment: Where can I read about it? Is it contained in Jboss (WildFly) tutorial?

Comment: I added some links to the post. Check out the dzone one first, should give you some idea about what is needed. Unfortunately config may differ a little in the newer versions of JBoss (be sure about the value of the module attribute).

Comment: Thank You for help. I have investigated this topic. I can now create my own login module, but I have one more problem. Can You take a look at it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026078/custom-login-module-and-httpservletrequest-authenticatehttpservletresponse-resp

Answer (score 4):

I believe the container independent way of doing this is to use JASPIC (JSR 196).  Unfortunately it doesn't appear simple, robust, or particularly well documented.  Here is a reference:  http://arjan-tijms.blogspot.com/2012/11/implementing-container-authentication.html.

Answer (score 1):

You should research JAAS.

Wikipedia gives a good overview:
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Authentication_and_Authorization_Service

This will provide all the info and tutorials you need: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/

Tutorial with sample app:
http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/tutorials/GeneralAcnOnly.html

And check this out in SO:
[JAAS for human beings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628416/jaas-for-human-beings)