# Is Spring Security JAAS-based?

Tags: java, spring-security

I've been doing some reading and I'm still not quite sure -- is Spring Security JAAS-based, or is it doing a thing of it's own? Could somebody please go into some more details and explain it to me, or maybe provide some useful links?

Thanks!

Comment: No, it isn't build on JAAS. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/694820/241990) provides a pretty good summary. If you want to secure something like a web application, for example, I'd recommend that you just forget that JAAS exists and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security works in application layer, JAAS is a more low level authentication method.

But you can use JAAS as a authentication provider to Spring Security.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.7.RELEASE/reference/jaas.html

Comment: Would you mind extending your answer a bit and explaining the differences?