# Server Authentication Module forwarding in Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, jaas, jaspic, jsr196

I found this guide for developing your own Server Authentication Module (SAM) for Glassfish: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/gizel.html

It seems pretty straightforward to verify some credentials (in HTTP Auth headers for instance), but my question is this:

Can I develop my SAM in such a way that I can forward the user to a specific page if he's not logged in?

Here's the example from the guide:

```
package tip.sam;

   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.Map;
   import javax.security.auth.Subject;
   import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
   import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
   import javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException;
   import javax.security.auth.message.AuthException;
   import javax.security.auth.message.AuthStatus;
   import javax.security.auth.message.MessageInfo;
   import javax.security.auth.message.MessagePolicy;
   import javax.security.auth.message.callback.CallerPrincipalCallback;
   import javax.security.auth.message.callback.GroupPrincipalCallback;
   import javax.security.auth.message.callback.PasswordValidationCallback;
   import javax.security.auth.message.module.ServerAuthModule;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
   import org.apache.catalina.util.Base64;

   public class MySam implements ServerAuthModule {

      protected static final Class[]
        supportedMessageTypes = new Class[]{
          HttpServletRequest.class,
          HttpServletResponse.class
      };

      private MessagePolicy requestPolicy;
      private MessagePolicy responsePolicy;
      private CallbackHandler handler;
      private Map options;
      private String realmName = null;
      private String defaultGroup[] = null;
      private static final String REALM_PROPERTY_NAME =
          "realm.name";
      private static final String GROUP_PROPERTY_NAME =
          "group.name";
      private static final String BASIC = "Basic";
      static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER =
          "authorization";
      static final String AUTHENTICATION_HEADER =
          "WWW-Authenticate";

      public void initialize(MessagePolicy reqPolicy,
              MessagePolicy resPolicy,
              CallbackHandler cBH, Map opts)
              throws AuthException {
          requestPolicy = reqPolicy;
          responsePolicy = resPolicy;
          handler = cBH;
          options = opts;
          if (options != null) {
              realmName = (String)
                  options.get(REALM_PROPERTY_NAME);
              if (options.containsKey(GROUP_PROPERTY_NAME)) {
                  defaultGroup = new String[]{(String)
                      options.get(GROUP_PROPERTY_NAME)};
              }
          }
      }

      public Class[] getSupportedMessageTypes() {
          return supportedMessageTypes;
      }

      public AuthStatus validateRequest(
              MessageInfo msgInfo, Subject client,
              Subject server) throws AuthException {
          try {

              String username =
                  processAuthorizationToken(msgInfo, client);
              if (username ==
                  null && requestPolicy.isMandatory()) {
                  return sendAuthenticateChallenge(msgInfo);
              }

             setAuthenticationResult(
                 username, client, msgInfo);
             return AuthStatus.SUCCESS;

          } catch (Exception e) {
              AuthException ae = new AuthException();
              ae.initCause(e);
              throw ae;
          }
      }

      private String processAuthorizationToken(
              MessageInfo msgInfo, Subject s)
              throws AuthException {

          HttpServletRequest request =
                  (HttpServletRequest)
                  msgInfo.getRequestMessage();

          String token =
                  request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER);

          if (token != null && token.startsWith(BASIC + " ")) {

              token = token.substring(6).trim();

              // Decode and parse the authorization token
              String decoded =
                  new String(Base64.decode(token.getBytes()));

              int colon = decoded.indexOf(':');
              if (colon <= 0 || colon == decoded.length() - 1) {
                  return (null);
              }

              String username = decoded.substring(0, colon);

             // use the callback to ask the container to
             // validate the password
            PasswordValidationCallback pVC =
                    new PasswordValidationCallback(s, username,
                    decoded.substring(colon + 1).toCharArray());
            try {
                handler.handle(new Callback[]{pVC});
                pVC.clearPassword();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                AuthException ae = new AuthException();
                ae.initCause(e);
                throw ae;
            }

            if (pVC.getResult()) {
                return username;
            }
      }
      return null;
   }

   private AuthStatus sendAuthenticateChallenge(
           MessageInfo msgInfo) {

       String realm = realmName;
         // if the realm property is set use it,
         // otherwise use the name of the server
         // as the realm name.
         if (realm == null) {

          HttpServletRequest request =
                  (HttpServletRequest)
                  msgInfo.getRequestMessage();

          realm = request.getServerName();
        }

       HttpServletResponse response =
               (HttpServletResponse)
               msgInfo.getResponseMessage();

       String header = BASIC + " realm=\"" + realm + "\"";
       response.setHeader(AUTHENTICATION_HEADER, header);
       response.setStatus(
               HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
       return AuthStatus.SEND_CONTINUE;
       // MAYBE SOMETHING HERE? 
   }

   public AuthStatus secureResponse(
           MessageInfo msgInfo, Subject service)
           throws AuthException {
       return AuthStatus.SEND_SUCCESS;
   }

   public void cleanSubject(MessageInfo msgInfo,
           Subject subject)
           throws AuthException {
      if (subject != null) {
          subject.getPrincipals().clear();
      }
   }

   private static final String AUTH_TYPE_INFO_KEY =
           "javax.servlet.http.authType";

   // distinguish the caller principal
   // and assign default groups
   private void setAuthenticationResult(String name,
           Subject s, MessageInfo m)
           throws IOException,
           UnsupportedCallbackException {
       handler.handle(new Callback[]{
           new CallerPrincipalCallback(s, name)
       });
       if (name != null) {
         // add the default group if the property is set
           if (defaultGroup != null) {
               handler.handle(new Callback[]{
                   new GroupPrincipalCallback(s, defaultGroup)
               });
           }
           m.getMap().put(AUTH_TYPE_INFO_KEY, ""MySAM");
       }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that in the `validateRequest` method.

Here is a simple example:

```
public AuthStatus validateRequest(MessageInfo messageInfo,
        Subject clientSubject,
        Subject serviceSubject) throws AuthException {

    // clientSubject.getPrincipals() returns the principals
    // check this set to know if the user is not logged in

    // if the user is not logged in do the following
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) messageInfo.getResponseMessage();
    response.sendRedirect("login.html");
}
```

It might be better to do it inside of a custom LoginModule (if you already know what that is), but I guess this depends on your requirements.

**See also:**

- [LoginModule Bridge Profile (JASPIC) in glassfish](https://blogs.oracle.com/nasradu8/entry/loginmodule_bridge_profile_jaspic_in)
- [Implementing container authentication in Java EE with JASPIC](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2012/11/implementing-container-authentication.html)
- [JAAS for human beings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628416/jaas-for-human-beings)

Comment: Thank you kindly for your response. Is it also possible, in a way like this, to get back to this page with say a token in HTTP Auth header and/or a session ID in a cookie which is validated?

Comment: I don't see a problem with that, you can read all values from the HttpServletRequest and you can modify the HttpServletResponse to set cookies or headers.

Comment: Okay, so I could implement the following scenario: Check session cookie, if not present (or not valid) and no token, redirect to other page and come back with token. If there is a token, make a session for it and put it as a cookie in the response.

Comment: Don't forget to return the correct `AuthStatus` from `validateRequest`, which is `SEND_CONTINUE` in this case.

Comment: `It might be better to do it inside of a custom LoginModule ` - If you mean the redirect here, then it's actually not better to do that there. The LoginModule should only do the bare authentication (lookup user, validate credentials then make user + group principals available), while the overarching SAM should take care of interaction with the user. A specially crafted callback could give the LoginModule some limited access to the request and response, but I don't think that should be used for real interaction, at most to get some basic values from the request.