# Servlet Filter login redirection infinite loop

Tags: servlets, authentication, infinite-loop, servlet-filters

I am experimentig with servlet filters. I have created two JSP pages - Home and Login.
I want to create the following flow:

When accessing the Home page without credentials in the session -> redirect to Login page.

When entering the correct credentials (compare them against hardcoded constants) redirect to the Home page.

When entering incorrect credential - redirect to Login page again.

Here is my code so far, I have an issue with an infinite loop when entering the home page directly, because of the null checks. Can you please give me directions on the right approach in this situation.

```
package bg.filter.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebFilter ("/pages/*")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    private static final String name = "admin";
    private static final String pass = "123";

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        String name = request.getParameter("username");
        String pass = request.getParameter("password");

        if (name != null && pass != null) {
            if (LoginFilter.name.equals(name) && LoginFilter.pass.equals(pass)) {
                ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().setAttribute("username", name);
                ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().setAttribute("password", pass);

                ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("/FilterLoginTest/pages/Home.jsp");
            } else {
                ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("/FilterLoginTest/pages/Login.jsp");
            }
        } else {
            name = (String)((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute("username");

            if(name == null) {
                ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("/FilterLoginTest/pages/Login.jsp");
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why do you want to implement it like that ,

Take a look at JAAS 
[JAAS for human beings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628416/jaas-for-human-beings)

Also if you need to implement this filter , it's a common behavior after login to put the user object for example in the session and just the filter will test it against null, 
if it's about authorization you will check the url for example against a predefined list of roles to pass the request or redirect to unauthorized page